# Consequences of Changing Column Name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

everyone.

I am currently messing around with rails and carrierwave. i've successfully uploaded and viewed images with it, but, after running a migration where i changed the the column name, the images would not show up in my application anymore. Only newly submitted images are visible.

not sure whats going on..

any insight?

Comment: Well if you change a column name you should change it also in your views, model, etc.

Comment: have you change folder name on `yourapp\public\uploads\yourmodel\..` ?

Comment: hey, pzin. Yea, i did change all those things. Anon, thanks it was the folder they were getting stored in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

apparently changing the column and the associated uploader will also create a new folder for the images to be stored in. thanks, anonymousxxx